# Redis - Sort and filter hash store using string attribute

Tags: redis

I have a redis hash store that looks like `Item:<id>`, with attribute `name`. I want to filter the hash store by a prefix for `name` attribute.
What I'm trying to do is store the name (lowercased) in a separate Z-set called `Item:::name` while setting the score to 0. By doing this, I'm successfully able to get the desired result using `ZRANGEBYLEX` however I'm unable to map the results back to the original `Items`. How should I go about implementing something like this?

I've seen multiple autocomplete examples for Redis which require the same functionality but without linking the words back to an actual Item (hash in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sorted sets` the `member` can't be duplicated, it has to be unique. So different users with the same name will cause problem.

My suggestion requires application layer coding to parse response array and executing `hash` commands (it will be like secondary indexes);

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET user:1 name jack
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET user:2 name john
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET user:3 name keanu
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET user:4 name jack
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD item:names 0 jack::user:1 0 john::user:2 0 keanu::user:3 0 jack::user:4
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE item:names 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "jack::user:1"
2) "0"
3) "jack::user:4"
4) "0"
5) "john::user:2"
6) "0"
7) "keanu::user:3"
8) "0"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX item:names [jack [jo
1) "jack::user:1"
2) "jack::user:4"
```

At the end you will have `name::hash-key` formatted array elements. At application layer if you separate each element to two substrings by using `::`(any other string such as `!!!` or `||` etc) you will have `user:1` and `user:4`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL user:1
1) "name"
2) "jack"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL user:4
1) "name"
2) "jack"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Although I was trying to find a way to do it without application layer processing but seems like this is the only way to go.